# Is it possible to use AWS Cognito Developer Identity for AWS AppSync?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-appsync

So I know AppSync has Cognito user pool to authenticate users to access the APIs. And it also has OpenID Connect as one of the authentication types.

[image]

My question is, is it possible to use Cognito Developer Identity to authenticate with AppSync? And if it's possible, how?

I tried putting in `cognito-identity.amazonaws.com` in the Issuer URL. However, it gives me an error

> Error: Issuer is not a valid URL

Answer (score 0):

It should be the exact value of the iss attribute from the ID token.   `https://cognito-identity.amazonaws.com` is what we're using with success...